# $.load() is not working in ie

Tags: php, jquery

i have the following code;

```
$("#testbtn").live("click", function(){
$("#targetdiv").load("http://localhost/test/test.php");
});
```

but it is not working in ie but working fine in chrome firefox safari etc...

Comment: How is it not working? Can you provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not working in IE, but it is in standards compliant browsers, it may just be a simple (or not so simple) CSS layout situation.

In a callback to the `load` method, do an alert to verify that the data was received.

```
$("#testbtn").live("click", function(){
    $("#targetdiv").load("http://localhost/test/test.php", function(data){alert(data);});
});
```

Comment: I think you mean the data passed to `$.loads`'s callback instead of the click handler.

Comment: yes it is alerting the data recieved that is same in the test.php but it is not showing it in #targetdiv

Comment: @testkhan - If it is not showing up only in IE, then it is likely an issue with your CSS layout. If you put some static content inside `#targetdiv` instead of using `load()`, does it appear? If not, then you know that the issue has nothing to do with `load()`.

Comment: @testkhan - ...or if static text does appear, then a CSS issue may exist solely in the loaded HTML.